# How to identify executable lines in C++ code

Tags: c++, parsing

How would one go about automatically identifying lines of C++ source files that contain (potentially) executable code?  By potentially excecutable code, I mean code that might have been executable had its template been instantiated.

I expect it would be a purely syntactic determination.  I'm not even completely sure this is even possible in all circumstances, but I guess it is.

Note that this is not the primary function of a dynamic coverage checker (although some may in fact perform this...)

(The goal is to enable a coverage checker to distinguish executable lines from comments, empty lines, type declarations, and the like.)

Comment: Define executable. Because I would say that the majority of lines of code in a C++ file are executable.

Comment: Basically https://godbolt.org/ does something like this by showing associated assembly code.

Comment: "The goal is to enable a coverage checker " most code coverage tools I have used already do this, although generally especially for C++ they still miss huge numbers of branches/implicit-code, don't handle macro's well, and some limitations over how template code is handled and displayed. So depends on exactly what you are wanting.

Comment: For code coverage, I use llvm, and the clang++ `-fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping` flags, and llvm-profdata and llvm-cov.

Comment: sweenish, By executable, I mean statements call functions or assign values to things at run-time.  This excludes declaratory lines, such as typedefs.
In template libraries, the vast bulk of the lines are often declaratory in nature.

Comment: Eljay, near as I can tell, fprofile-instr-generate -fcoverage-mapping is about run-time coverage.  The question is about (potentially) executable code, not about which lines were in fact executed in a run.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Fire Lancer, yes, what you mention is exactly the problem.  The question is, does there exist a good way to identify (syntactially) which lines were potentially executable, but were somehow ommitted from the test suite?

Answer (score -1):

If you work with [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/fr-fr/clion/) IDE, you can use the pluging [C/C++ Coverage](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11031-c-c--coverage).